# How to Extract a small sample data from a big database in SQL server 2012 whose schema is a little complex

Tags: sql-server

There is a big Database in my SQL server, and I need a small sample data set to do some experiments. I hope to create a Database with the same schema. 
The Database is in SQL server 2012.
Are there any convenient methods to achieve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [DBSourceTools](http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com/).  It will be able to script the full database schema to disk, then re-create it on another instance.
There is an option on the source databases to select which tables to script, and which tables to script data for.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to copy 100 records from a table called `Customers` into another database:

```
SELECT top 100 * INTO CustomersBackupTable IN 'Backup.mdb' FROM Customers;
```

This will copy the structure and the data. Do this for all the tables you need to copy.